# OpenSSL ECDH key exchang mechanism

Tags: openssl, cryptography, fips

I am using FIPS based OpenSSL module for encryption of sensitive data for my desktop socket server and client applications. I am using ECDH for key agreement.The keys public and private pair is generated for server and client on same curve NID_secp521r1. Now I want to exchange the public key between client and server and has following questions.

The generated private key is same for both client and server is it true?
Client send its public key first or Server? The public key should be send plain or it should be signed? If signed then what will be the mechanism?
I want to reuse my public/private key on server where I store that keys in application exe? PEM file? Any other options?

Comment: What's wrong with using TLS directly?

Comment: My server is not http based, I have scalable version of socket(iocp) and I dont want to encrypyt whole traffic only sensitive.

Comment: Where I can store keys?